# google map api v3: can I use a div instead of an image to create the custom icon?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

google map api v3: can I use a div instead of an image to create the custom icon?

i want to be able to hover the marker and change the icon, ven betetr if i could use a fade fx...so how can i set a div instead of an image like it is by default?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You can use Custom Overlays in place of markers:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays

Answer (score 0):

First, I give the demo-purpose [website](http://easysublease.org/mapcoverjs/).

For this question, I have found there are several similar questions which I have already answered such as:

(following one is about theory)

[HTML/CSS Markers using Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678685/html-css-markers-using-google-maps-javascript-api-v3/31545004#31545004)

(following one is about implementations)

[How to create custom marker for google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982202/how-to-create-custom-marker-for-google-map/31530390#31530390)

At first answer, I have given my detailed understanding why customized icons and markers should be implemented by extending `overlayView` class. 
At second answer, I have posted out how to write HTML/CSS to specify how one customized icon/marker looks. Of course you can also write event handlers to add JS logic to your icon/marker.

At stack overflow, I found several interesting points. When I found similar questions, I cannot answer the question using my previous answer. 
One content manager even deletes my answer although  what I am answering here is exactly the question is asking.

At last, if you need to see how to extend `overlayView` class to realize one marker, please see this [source code](https://github.com/bovetliu/mapcover/blob/master/assets/js/mapcover.js) (starting below comment `//====custom-marker management starts`)

Thank you.